# inverse document frequency

Tags: search, lucene, full-text-search, lucene.net

The inverse document freqency is defined as follows:

IDF(term,document) = tf(term) * log(1 + n/df(term))

where tf(term) = 'frequency of term in document', n = 'number of documents', df(term) = 'number of docs containing term'.

Just curious about df(term) - do I only count a document ones even if it contains the term more than once?

Also is it easy to determine this stat with lucene(.net)? I am only starting to use the latter and use a relational db at the moment.

Thanks.

Christian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For using idf with Lucene, [check the API for example here.](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_2_0/api/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html)

You are right about the docs being counted only once. The idea is to get a function with a lower bound in the log part. Like this:

[image]

If you are interested in the idf theory behind the scenes, you may peep at [this paper.](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/N/N01/N01-1004.pdf)

HTH!

Comment: Thanks excellent - I will have to digest the paper. The API link points to the paper - could this be a mistake? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I am still quite ignorant about the lucene api but how do I get the IDF given a document and a term (as in single word)? idf(Term term, Searcher searcher) comes close but not sure about it ...

Comment: @csetzkom It's this one http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html#idf%28org.apache.lucene.index.Term,%20org.apache.lucene.search.Searcher%29

Answer (score 1):

Of course you have to  count the DF(term) once. therefore, you should group the words to get distinct words.

[See my class IDF here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/19143/inverse-document-frequency-idf-implementation)